# String length modification in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How can I fix a length of strings to be 10, i.e. an input string will always have less than or 10 characters. If it has less than 10 characters, I have to add 0's at the beginning of the string.

Example of input:

```
123456
1234567
```

Needed output:

```
0000123456
0001234567
```

Input is arbitrary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String#rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-rjust) does just that:

```
'1234567'.rjust(10, '0') # => "0001234567"
```

Comment: Turns out my method is faster whereas `rjust` is more reliable. I.e. if your input string is > 10 characters long my method throws an exception whereas your's just returns the original argument.

Comment: @Killerpixler, for higher `n = 5_000_000` I consistently get the opposite result (~1.14 vs ~ 1.19 in favour of `#rjust`). But does it really matter? If there is a dedicated method just use it. Such micro-optimizations should only be considered if you identified this as a performance bottleneck to begin with.

Comment: of course it doesn't matter, just thought it was interesting that something that seems more complicated than the dedicated method was faster. And even for 5_000_000 I still get results more favorable for the other method. (1.519720 vs 1.486935)

Comment: @Killerpixler: The possibility of raising an exception is worse than losing a few ms.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "123456"
b = "1234567"

"0"*(10-a.size)+a
=> "0000123456"
"0"*(10-b.size)+b
=> "0001234567"
```

Interestingly for speed purposes:

```
a = "123456"
n = 50000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report{n.times do ; a.rjust(10,'0'); end}
  x.report{n.times do ; "0"*(10-a.size)+a; end}
end
       user     system      total        real
   0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.016442)
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.015134)
```

or a even higher sample size:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'benchmark'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> a = "123456"
=> "123456"
irb(main):003:0> n = 5_000_000
=> 5000000
irb(main):004:0> Benchmark.bm do |x|
irb(main):005:1*   x.report{n.times do ; a.rjust(10,'0'); end}
irb(main):006:1>   x.report{n.times do ; "0"*(10-a.size)+a; end}
irb(main):007:1> end
       user     system      total        real
   1.510000   0.000000   1.510000 (  1.519720)
   1.480000   0.000000   1.480000 (  1.486935)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. On my system, `rjust` is faster. And the difference becomes more obvious with larger string size, e.g. 1000 instead of 10.

Comment: Interesting I consistently get faster results not using `rjust`. I've tried this on both my local (i7, SSD) as well as a remote server (xeon, ssd). And as for longer string size, this doesn't apply here since the OP clearly stated a length of 10. In any case the differences are so small (2%) that this is mostly academic anyways.

Comment: Maybe it's due to garbage collection. Have you tried `Benchmark.bmbm`?

Comment: What Ruby version are you using?

Comment: `2.3.0` and `.2.3.3` on my local and remote respectively. `bmbm` returns similar results with `rjust` being ~1%` faster for an `n` of 5 million.